# Units used by hb_position_t in HarfBuzz

Tags: harfbuzz

I've been looking at [this page](https://harfbuzz.github.io/hello-harfbuzz.html), as well as [this code example](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz-tutorial/blob/master/hello-harfbuzz-freetype.c) and I've noticed that the `x_advance`, `y_advance`, `x_offset` and `y_offset` fields in `hb_glyph_position_t` are of the type `hb_position_t`, which is an alias to `int32_t`. I haven't found any documentation about which units are used for these fields. The examples above suggest that they're 64ths of something, but that's all I can infer.

Does anyone else know the exact unit implied by `hb_position_t`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in input font size units (say pixels).

The idea there is you multiply the input font size [by 64](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz-tutorial/blob/master/hello-harfbuzz-freetype.c#L36) then you divide the position [by 64](https://github.com/harfbuzz/harfbuzz-tutorial/blob/master/hello-harfbuzz-freetype.c#L63-L66) after the shaping so you will be in control of how much sub pixel precision you need.